# Showing error not updating values in database

Tags: php

I made a form containing two fields firstname and lastname but when i run the code below it shows error undefined variable and the values are not inserted in the database.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$dbname="myfd";
$conn=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
if($conn->connect_error){
echo "error";
}
else{
echo "successfull";
}
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
$fname=$_POST["firstname"];
$lname=$_POST["lastname"];
$myfd_query="INSERT INTO 'logi'('$fname','$lname') 
VALUES('$fname','$lname')";
}
try {
$myfd_result = mysqli_query($conn, $myfd_query);
if ($myfd_result) {
echo "successfull";
} else {
echo "error";
}
}
catch (Exception $exception){
echo "error";
}
?>
```

Comment: For which variable it gives as undefined?

Comment: can u connect to DB?

Comment: Post the error to help us friend! [Please see this article](https://academy.iget.com.br/en/debug-2/read-the-errors/) to understand why you need to read the errors, and probably understant why you code fails.

Comment: `INSERT INTO logi`

Comment: undefined for $myfd_result. Yes i can connect to db. Notice: Undefined variable: myfd_query in C:\xampp\htdocs\myf\home.php on line 20 this is the error.

Answer (score 0):

The variable name given in wrong way.please update variable name.

Insert query Syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: myfd_query in C:\xampp\htdocs\myf\home.php on line 20

Comment: successfull
Notice: Undefined variable: myfd_query in C:\xampp\htdocs\myf\home.php on line 21

Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in C:\xampp\htdocs\myf\home.php on line 21
error

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your query

```
$myfd_query="INSERT INTO `logi`(`firstname`,`lastname`) 
VALUES('".$fname."','".$lname."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$dbname="myfd";
$conn=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
if($conn->connect_error){
echo "error";
}
else{
echo "successfull";
}
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
$fname=$_POST["firstname"];
$lname=$_POST["lastname"];
$myfd_query="INSERT INTO 'logi'('$fname','$lname') 
VALUES('$fname','$lname')";
try {
$myfd_result = mysqli_query($conn, $myfd_query);
if ($myfd_result) {
echo "successfull";
} else {
echo "error";
}
}
catch (Exception $exception){
echo "error";
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because scope of this variable $myfd_query is only inside if block. Try declaring that query outside or try use it in same scope. May also give this a try:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "myfd";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    echo "error";
} else {
    echo "successfull";
}
$myfd_query = "";
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $fname = $_POST["firstname"];
    $lname = $_POST["lastname"];
    $myfd_query = "INSERT INTO 'logi'('$fname','$lname') 
VALUES('$fname','$lname')";
}
try {
    $myfd_result = mysqli_query($conn, $myfd_query);
    if ($myfd_result) {
        echo "successfull";
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    echo "error";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, please, please, always format your code. It will be much more easier to understand it, even for the author of that code.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$dbname="myfd";
$conn=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$dbname);
if($conn->connect_error){
    echo "error";
} else{
    echo "successfull";
}
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $fname=$_POST["firstname"];
    $lname=$_POST["lastname"];
    $myfd_query="INSERT INTO 'logi'('$fname','$lname') VALUES('$fname','$lname')";
}
try {
    $myfd_result = mysqli_query($conn, $myfd_query);
    if ($myfd_result) {
        echo "successfull";
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }
} catch (Exception $exception){
    echo "error";
}
```

well, here we go.

Problem number 1. in case of connection error, script will show `error` text and continue excecution.

Problem 2. look, you set variable only when `isset($_POST["submit"])` but always execute query.

Problem 3. your query is wrong. instead of 
`$myfd_query="INSERT INTO 'logi'('$fname','$lname') VALUES('$fname','$lname')";` should be something like: `$myfd_query="INSERT INTO 'logi'(firstname,lastname) VALUES('$fname','$lname')";`, however (i do not know exact names of fields in your **logi** table)

Problem 4. Do not quote table name by ' or " symbols, some mysql configurations do not accept table name in quotes. Better to use backtick symbol: `

Problem 5. Better to use placeholders, instead of putting variables inside string. It's way to SQL injections. And it's better to get practise to always use placeholders.
Please see example [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php#77107)